# voice over ip between desktop and android

Tags: java, android, sockets, voip

i am trying to transfer audio between android and desktop in real time. i have developed to applications, one for android and one for desktop.
desktop application is successfully working for real time audio transfer between 2 desktops and android application is successfully working for audio transfer between two android devices. 
i am using local ip addresses and ports for this process (in both applications).

PROBLEM is when i try to transfer audio between android and desktop (using same applications) its not working. 
i am able to transfer only one way audio, for example at a time desktop either is receiving voice or transmitting it.

please help

here is code for android app

```
    package com.example.myrtpapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.rtp.AudioCodec;
import android.net.rtp.AudioGroup;
import android.net.rtp.AudioStream;
import android.net.rtp.RtpStream;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText remote_ip_editText;
    EditText remote_port_editText;
    TextView locolport;
    AudioStream audioStream;
    AudioGroup audioGroup;
    String localip;
    Handler handler;
    int flag=0;
    private static int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=1;
    private String[] PERMISSIONS={
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        verifyPermissions(MainActivity.this);
        if(flag==1) {
            locolport = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lp);
            remote_ip_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remote_ip);
            remote_port_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remote_port);
            handler = new Handler();

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            int line = 0;
            try {

                AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audiomanager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
                audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                //  audiomanager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                if (audiomanager.isMicrophoneMute()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Microphone is mute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
                audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_ECHO_SUPPRESSION);
                localip = getLocalAddress().toString();


                audioStream = new AudioStream(getLocalAddress());
                locolport.append(String.valueOf(audioStream.getLocalPort()));
                audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
                audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "line = 10", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (SocketException se) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, se.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "line = " + line + e.getMessage() + "\n" + localip, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("-------", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permissions denied rizi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void call(View view)
    {
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, remote_ip_editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            InetAddress remoteIp = InetAddress.getByName(remote_ip_editText.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, remote_port_editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Integer remotePort= Integer.parseInt(remote_port_editText.getText().toString());
            audioStream.associate(remoteIp, remotePort);
            audioStream.join(audioGroup);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "call Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException ex){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unkown host Exception "+ ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception "+ e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    public InetAddress getLocalAddress()
    {
        InetAddress localAddress;
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = networkInterface.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    InetAddress ip = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!ip.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        if (ip.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                            return ip;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception at get local Address"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public  void verifyPermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission1= ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        int permission2= ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        int permission3= ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);



        if (permission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || permission3 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }else{
            flag=1;
        }
    }

}
```

here is code for desktop app. i am using 2 classes in desktop app transmitter class and receiver class. and i am using these classes in main method as a thread.

Reciever Class

```
package rtpstreamdesktop;




import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;



public class SimpleVoiceReceiver implements Runnable
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
   public void run(){




            // ip and port declaration for rtp session
        String url = "rtp://192.168.8.106:60002/audio/16";

        MediaLocator mrl = new MediaLocator(url);

        // Create a player for this rtp session
        Player player = null;
        try
        {
            player = Manager.createPlayer(mrl);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
                    System.out.println("player creation exception");
                }

        if (player != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Player created: ");
            player.realize();
            // wait for realizing (construction of media player)
            while (player.getState() != Player.Realized)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Starting player: ");
            player.start();
        } else
        {
            System.err.println("Player doesn't created: ");
            System.exit(-1);
        }


    }

}
```

Transmitter Class

```
package rtpstreamdesktop;



import java.util.Vector;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceManager;
import javax.media.DataSink;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.NotRealizedError;
import javax.media.Processor;
import javax.media.control.FormatControl;
import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;


/**
 * 
 * @author Abdul Rab
 *
 */
public class SimpleVoiceTransmiter implements Runnable
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public void run()
    {
                CaptureDeviceInfo di = null;
        Format format;
        format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.ULAW_RTP, 8000, 8, 1);
            // First find a capture device that will capture linear audio
            // data at 8bit 8Khz
        AudioFormat captureFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR, 8000, 16, 1);

        Vector devices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(captureFormat);



        if (devices.size() > 0)
            {
                di = (CaptureDeviceInfo) devices.elementAt(0);
            } else
            {
                System.err.println("No capture devices");
                // exit if we could not find the relevant capturedevice.
                System.exit(-1);
            }


        // Create a processor for this capturedevice & exit if we
        // cannot create it
        Processor processor = null;
        try
        {
                    processor = Manager.createProcessor(di.getLocator());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
                    System.out.println("Procesor Exception: ");
                }

        // configure the processor
        processor.configure();

        while (processor.getState() != Processor.Configured)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                 System.out.println("interupted processor exception: ");
            }
        }

        processor.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP));

        TrackControl track[] = processor.getTrackControls();

        boolean encodingOk = false;

        // Go through the tracks and try to program one of them to
        // output gsm data.

        for (int i = 0; i < track.length; i++)
        {
            if (!encodingOk && track[i] instanceof FormatControl)
            {
                if (((FormatControl) track[i]).setFormat(format) == null)
                {

                    track[i].setEnabled(false);
                } else
                {
                    encodingOk = true;
                }
            } else
            {
                // we could not set this track to gsm, so disable it
                track[i].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        // At this point, we have determined where we can send out
        // gsm data or not.
        // realize the processor
        if (encodingOk)
        {
            if (!new net.sf.fmj.ejmf.toolkit.util.StateWaiter(processor).blockingRealize())
            {
                System.err.println("Failed to realize");
                return;
            }

            // get the output datasource of the processor and exit
            // if we fail
            DataSource ds = null;

            try
            {
                ds = processor.getDataOutput();
            } catch (NotRealizedError e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            // hand this datasource to manager for creating an RTP
            // datasink our RTP datasink will multicast the audio
            try
            {
                String url = "rtp://192.168.8.102:60010/audio/16";

                MediaLocator m = new MediaLocator(url);

                DataSink d = Manager.createDataSink(ds, m);
                d.open();
                d.start();

                System.out.println("Starting processor");
                processor.start();
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                            System.out.println("RTP connection exception: ");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Main Class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package rtpstreamdesktop;



/**
 *
 * @author Rizwan
 */
public class RtpStreamDesktop {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Thread(new SimpleVoiceReceiver()).start();
         new Thread(new SimpleVoiceTransmiter()).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: You must put forward more effort to craft [a create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i think i declared everything already.. please tell me what you didnt get about it @JamesKPolk. i will explain it further

Comment: Read the link please.

Comment: i have provided complete code. you can just copy and paste to test it and it will produce the same problem.
i can not provide minimal the reason is that i also don't know the exact part of the code causing problem

Comment: It takes some effort to provide a minimal example, but that is effort that you must put in, not us.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undesrtand how your code work also in one direction, because your are using (correctly) Android.net.rtp package in Android side (than you are sending/receiving Voip packets), while it seems that you doesn't have on PC side any Voip Module; in your code you are trying to play Voip packets with MediaLocator, but Voip packets are not a media file (like mp3).

The solution could be, in my opinion, on PC side, to import a Voip Java Module (there are some open source like 'pjsip') but you have to adapt and study it. This part is time consuming and not easy because you have to understand a little bit how voip works, etc...

Ciao, Fausto

Comment: thanks a lot Ciao, i really appreciate it. i surely will give it a try